# Fast updates mass data mysql from csv with php

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, bulk-load, bulkupdate

I'm trying to update my database with php. unfortunately the process is far too long. I can't use a data load infile because my hosting doesn't allow it.

My database rows ( id, sku, stock, image_1, image_2, image_3)
my csv file ( sku, stock)

i try to update only the stock from csv file into my database.

```
<?php      
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "databsename", "PAssword", "databsename");
    $handle = fopen("new_stock.csv", "r");
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle))
    {
        $sku = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]); 
        $stock = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);   
        $query = "UPDATE Products SET stock='$stock' WHERE sku='$sku'";
        mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo 'finish';
?>
```

Comment: (Possible) side note: Forget about `*escape_string*()` and do not use string interpolation or concatenation to get values into SQL queries. That's error prone and might make (still leave) your program vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Use parameterized queries. See ["How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537377/how-to-include-a-php-variable-inside-a-mysql-statement) and ["How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: `is far too long` means you hit execution time limit or what?

Comment: no, I mean that it takes too long to update all stocks

Comment: With respect I disagree with the decision to close this question for lack of details. It presents the questioner's problem quite clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the following code, you can do that. I had the same problem.

```
set_time_limit(0);
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "databsename", "PAssword", "databsename");
$handle = fopen("new_stock.csv", "r");
$str = [];
$flag = true;
$counter = 0;
$str2 = "";
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    if ($flag) {
        $flag = false;
        continue;
    };
    
    $sku = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[0]); 
    $stock = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $data[1]);   
    $query = "UPDATE Products SET stock='$stock' WHERE sku='$sku'; ";

   
    $counter++;
    $str2 .= $query;
    if ($counter % 10000 == 0) {
        $str[] = $str2;
        $str2 = "";
    }
}

fclose($handle);
if ($str2 != "")
    $str[] = $str2;
    

foreach ($str as $item) {
    $item2 = str_replace('\"', '"', $item2);
    mysqli_query($connect, $item);
}
echo 'finish';
```

Comment: then the script runs for several hours right?

Comment: No. Why several hours? It will done as its work ends. And it will be pretty fast I guess.

Comment: is this correct ? 

$handle = fopen("new_stock.csv", "r");
$file = fopen($handle);

Comment: You right. sorry. I edited my answer.

Comment: And $connect must be at the top ?

Comment: bro your code not work

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to place multiple UPDATE operations in a single [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html). Why? MySQL does the bulk of its UPDATE and INSERT work when you COMMIT your work. Therefore, fewer transactions lead to faster operations. Ordinarily mysqli uses "autocommit" mode, meaning each statement is its own transaction. But here we use [mysqli_begin_transaction()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) and [mysqli_commit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php).

Something like this will work (not! debugged). It also uses a [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and bind variables in place of the deprecated `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

```php
    $transactionSize = 500;
    $handle = fopen("new_stock.csv", "r");
    $countdown = $transactionSize;
    mysqli_begin_transaction($connection);
    $updateStatement = mysqli_prepare($connection, 
                        "UPDATE Products SET stock=? WHERE sku=?");
    while($data = fgetcsv($handle)) {
        set_time_limit(30);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($updateStatement , "ss", $data[0], $data[1]);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($updateStatement);
        $countdown--;
        if ($countdown <= 0) {
           /* end one transaction, start another */
           mysqli_commit($connection);
           mysqli_begin_transaction($connection);
           $countdown = $transactionSize
        }
    }
    mysqli_commit($connection);
    fclose($handle);
    echo 'finish';
?>
```

This code pattern, or something similar, is useful for all sorts of multirow INSERTs and UPDATEs.

Comment: then the script runs for several hours right?

Comment: With code like mine it should run somewhere between 10 and 100 times faster than it would with your sample code.

Comment: Interesting code! Really pro!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I've done this kind of thing too many times :-)

Comment: the script takes a very long time with 350,000 data records

Comment: Gateway Timeout
The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application